# How to get a gradient background for table rows with JSF and CSS?

Tags: css, jsf, background, gradient

I can create a gradient background on the rows (see screenshot), but this is hard-coded to 10 rows. The gradient is repeated when there are more than 10 rows.

Can I create a gradient (from white to black) with a dynamically number of rows (5 row, 10 rows, 21 rows, .. depending on the datasource)

This would be a nice JSF exam question, but I can't figure it out...

DataTable

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="default" name="css/style.css" />
<h:dataTable id="persons" value="#{tableBean.persons}" var="person"
             rowClasses="list-row-1, list-row-2, list-row-3, list-row-4, list-row-5, list-row-6, list-row-7, list-row-8, list-row-9, list-row-10">
    <h:column><h:outputLabel value="#{person.firstName}" /></h:column>
    <h:column><h:outputLabel value="#{person.lastName}" /></h:column>
    <h:column><h:outputLabel value="#{person.jobTitle}" /></h:column>
    <h:column><h:outputLabel value="#{person.birthDate}" /></h:column>
    <h:column><h:outputLabel value="#{person.age}" /></h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

StyleCheet: default/1_0/css/style.css

```
.list-row-1 {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
.list-row-2 {
    background-color: #EEE;
}
.list-row-3 {
    background-color: #DDD;
}
.list-row-4 {
    background-color: #CCC;
}
.list-row-5 {
    background-color: #BBB;
}
.list-row-6 {
    background-color: #AAA;
}
.list-row-7 {
    background-color: #999;
}
.list-row-8 {
    background-color: #888;
}
.list-row-9 {
    background-color: #777;
}
.list-row-10 {
    background-color: #666;
}
```

***Can this be done with a Bean?*** The Gradient should be calculated and fit the total numbers of rows: white=first row; black is last row.

Comment: Just use `rowClasses="#{bean.calculatedRowClasses}"` or so with the appropriate bean logic? Or put it as background of whole table itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:

I updated the dataTable like this:

```
<h:dataTable id="persons" value="#{tableBean.persons}" var="person" rowClasses="#{tableBean.calculatedRowClasses}">
```

So, with a bean: rowClasses="#{tableBean.calculatedRowClasses}"

Then I calculate the necessary CSS elements to add in a long string:

```
public String getCalculatedRowClasses() {
    StringBuilder build = new StringBuilder();

    int total = persons.size();
    int factor = 99 / total;    //divide an integer results in an interger

    build.append("list-row-0");
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        build.append(",");
        build.append("list-row-").append(i * factor);   //divide the css over the 100 available in style.css
    }

    return build.toString();
}
```

This is not the best solution, but it works this case...